# Bash: how to erase the error message produced by xargs from output?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have these commands here for looking at files to see if they contain a certain regular expression:

`find / -type f | xargs grep -ilIs <regex>`

It seems to do what it's supposed to (looking at every file on my desktop for the expression), but ideally i wouldn't show this error message because it's only commenting on unmatched single quotes within a files that the above command finds:

`xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option`

I've tried to use sed to get rid of the error message but using `| sed '/xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option/d'` after the commands does not remove it like i think it should. I'm wondering if any of you know of any tools (ideally with the best ease of reading and least amount of typing, of course) that would get rid of the xargs error message. Including `-0` as an argument doesn't return anything except this:

`xargs: argument line too long`

Comment: @Fravadona, That would be fine as a general answer even though i am having a problem running that (it gets stuck in the middle of its operations, maybe it has exceeded the xarg argument limit), even though the way i'm using it doesn't work entirely it does get rid of the error message and it would be interesting to see an explanation of that command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xargs` have it's own escaping syntax, for example:

```bash
$ echo 'file 1.txt' | xargs printf '<%s>\n'
<file>
<1.txt>
$ echo '"file 1.txt"' | xargs printf '<%s>\n'
<file 1.txt>
```

So you CANNOT feed it raw filepaths, because they can contain ANY character but the `NUL` byte.

For working around that, most implementations of `xargs` have the `-0` switch which allows to process `NUL`-delimited records, but you need to provide the `NUL` bytes in the input stream:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' 'file 1.txt' 'file 2.txt' | xargs -0 printf '<%s>\n'
<file 1.txt
file 2.txt
>
$ printf '%s\0' 'file 1.txt' 'file 2.txt' | xargs -0 printf '<%s>\n'
<file 1.txt>
<file 2.txt>
```

---

Finally, you have three ways to do the task correctly:

1. `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 grep ...`

```bash
find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -ilIs 'regex'
```

2. `find ... -exec grep ... {} +`

```bash
find / -type f -exec grep -ilIs 'regex' {} +
```

3. `grep -R ...`

```bash
grep -iRlIs 'regex' /
```

Comment: that definetly takes care of the problem i presented, even though those both have issues with going through the entire filesystem, they both get stuck.

Comment: @thinksinbinary Well, going through the whole filesystem will sure take a lot of time. BTW I added an other solution

Comment: thank you for that, i don't know what to do but i guess it would be worthwhile to let those programs try to complete for over an hour to at least see if it gives me error messages.